# Array in Input text Field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS Community and I am practicing JS. I have Input text field where User will enter the array like `1,2-5,6-9,10,12,13-15` . What I am trying is to expand this array like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15`

```
<input class="inputC" id="inputC" type="text" value="" placeholder="Select Control" required />
```

JS I tried

```
var items = $('#inputC').val().split(",");
for (var i in items) {
  console.log(items[i]);
}
```

Comment: You need to check if there is any item with "-" and add all numbers in between.

Comment: That does not make any sense when you excluded `11` in the input then how is `11` in the output. You can directly input `1-15`??

Comment: Will you allow duplicates?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal It was Just an Example.

Comment: @connexo No Sir. Its should be unique

Comment: My answer now delivers unique values, sorted in ascending order. Try inputting `17, 9-11, 17, 3`.

Comment: You've picked the lowest quality answer.

Comment: @aryanvishwakarma Output code is not an example there is a lot of difference in saying `2 + 2 = 4` and `2 + 2 = 22`.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Sorry Sir. Next time I'll be very careful while giving the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** You should specify the logic of adding `11` in the output based on the given input.

You should split on `-` as well which you can do inside a map call back function.

**Demo:**

```js
var items = $('#inputC').val().split(',');
items = items.flatMap(i =>{
  var list = [];
  i = i.split('-');
  if(i.length > 1){
    for (var j = i[0]; j <= i[1]; j++) {
        list.push(+j);
    }
  }
  else{
    list.push(+i[0]);
  }
  return list;
});
console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inputC" id="inputC" value="1,2-5,6-9,10,12,13-15" type="text" value="" placeholder="Select Control" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str='1,2-5,6-9,10,12,13-15';
str.split(',').map((e)=>{
    if(e.includes('-')){
      const values = e.split('-');
      const end   = parseInt(values[1]);
      let start = parseInt(values[0]);
      while(start < end){
        console.log(start);start++;
      }
    }else{
      console.log(parseInt(e))
    } 
 })
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your Help

Comment: @aryanvishwakarma You are always welcome. I tried to write the code clean as much i can for better understanding. If this really helpful for you, then kindly mark this as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Code-only answer are almost never good answers. Yours is no exception.

Comment: @aryanvishwakarma ! I just noticed that answer is again marked as unaccepted. Can i ask what exactly the difference you really feel in the current excepted answer ?

Comment: @MuhammadAtifAkram Mamun Sir has tried simplify the code which is understandable to me. As I am new to this some terms from your code I am not able to understand. but Thank you Sir for your Help.

Comment: @aryanvishwakarma excellent work  Really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a great scenario in which you want to create a small derived **webcomponent** that does just what you need:

```
<input is="array-input" />
```

```js
class ArrayInput extends HTMLInputElement {
  get value() {
    let inter = super.value.split(',').map(el => el.trim());
    let ret = [];
    for (const el of inter) {
      const [ start, end ] = el.split('-').map(Number);
      if (isNaN(start)) continue;
      if (!end || start > end) {
        ret.push(start);
      } else if (start === end) {
        ret.push(start)
      } else if (start < end) {
        for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
          ret.push(i);
        }
      }
    }
    return [...new Set(ret)].sort();
  }
}

customElements.define('array-input', ArrayInput, {
  extends: 'input'
});
```

```html
<input is="array-input" onchange="console.log(this.value)" />
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your Help